# Creating video from sequence of bitmaps

Tags: android, image, video, bitmap

Hi i want to convert sequence of bitmaps in to video is this possible ???. Is there any library or link or sample code please let me know. In stack overflow man people suggested to use "ffmpeg" sample and some native code I do not know how to use these things I am very new to these things.

Comment: Frame-by-Frame animation is the simple one to do this.

Comment: thanks Nizam for your reply. But i need to save that one as a video so